# WebDAV service in a JEE application

Tags: web-apps, java, authentication, webdav

The task to accomplish:

- I need to provide a WebDAV level 2 service (with file locking etc.) from a standard web application (JEE, Spring, JPA/Hibernate, etc.)

Here are my requirements:

- It must be secured - operations should be possible only to authenticated users
- I don't need complex authorisations model - being logged in is enough to access everything
- I need to share the authentication mechanism (implemented with Spring Security) from my webapp with the DAV repository, to avoid the user to login once on my app, and once in the dav repo
- I need a cost-free solution. Open Source is nice-to-have, but not mandatory.
- It should be deployable under WebSphere 8.5.x

What we already tried:

- configuring DAV repository directly under WebSphere IHS (ApacheHTTP fork?). Works, but this seems difficult to share authentication between the webapp and the dav. (Could somebody add a comment about this?)
- using a Java library to expose the DAV repo directly from the webapp

  - using `org.apache.catalina.servlets.WebdavServlet` from Tomcat Catalina: it may work and could be a possible workaround if nothing else work, but adding a dependency to catalina.jar for such a thing seems rather evil to me...
  - using an external API like http://milton.io/downloads/ is exactly what I'm looking for, but with an open licence

How would you address my requirements in your webapps? Any advice or comment?

PS: SSO is unfortunately NOT an option

Thanks

Comment: I've got some success at the moment with the dependency: org.commonjava.web:webdav-handler-servlet:3.2.1, available here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.commonjava.web/webdav-handler-servlet/3.2.1. So far, this seems to do the job, I'm still watching if it is stable enough to go to production.